# Java screenshot of certain App in MacOS

Tags: java, macos, screenshot

I want to take screenshot of certain app in my MacOS, even if on another virtual screen and not in active screen.

I can take active screen capture with following code but how to capture given application?

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Screenshot {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws AWTException, IOException {
        while(true) {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());

            BufferedImage screencapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(
                new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize())
            );

            // Save as JPEG
            File file = new File("./screens/screencapture" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
            ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", file);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you identify the window you want to capture?

Comment: @MadProgrammer No idea, can be fixed app in code

Answer (score 5):

Try using /usr/sbin/screencapture, and calling it with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/sbin/screencapture");
```

Here is the usage output of screencapture

```
usage: screencapture [-icMPmwsWxSCUtoa] [files]
  -c         force screen capture to go to the clipboard
  -C         capture the cursor as well as the screen. only in non-interactive modes
  -d         display errors to the user graphically
  -i         capture screen interactively, by selection or window
               control key - causes screen shot to go to clipboard
               space key   - toggle between mouse selection and
                             window selection modes
               escape key  - cancels interactive screen shot
  -m         only capture the main monitor, undefined if -i is set
  -M         screen capture output will go to a new Mail message
  -o         in window capture mode, do not capture the shadow of the window
  -P         screen capture output will open in Preview
  -s         only allow mouse selection mode
  -S         in window capture mode, capture the screen not the window
  -t<format> image format to create, default is png (other options include pdf, jpg, tiff and other formats)
  -T<seconds> Take the picture after a delay of <seconds>, default is 5
  -w         only allow window selection mode
  -W         start interaction in window selection mode
  -x         do not play sounds
  -a         do not include windows attached to selected windows
  -r         do not add dpi meta data to image
  -l<windowid> capture this windowsid
  -R<x,y,w,h> capture screen rect
  files   where to save the screen capture, 1 file per screen
```

I think the -w option with window id is the one to use. But to get the window id, you will probably need another utility. One such utility is [pyscreencapture](https://github.com/thismachinechills/pyscreencapture).
Otherwise I am sure googling how to get the window id will result in more ways to get the window id you require.

Though I am not entirely sure what you mean by virtual screen, and you may have problem with obtaining the window id or capturing the screen.

Comment: virtual desktop: http://www.howtogeek.com/180677/mission-control-101-how-to-use-multiple-desktops-on-a-mac/

Comment: ah, I know virtual desktops. Was not too sure about the term virtual screens. Thought it was something to do with an app running on virtualbox with the mac as a guest OS.

Comment: I wanted to use screencapture with pid but it opens interactively.

Answer (score 4):

"Unfortunately" you need JNI here. Basically you'll need to access some of the `CoreGraphics` and `ImageIO` APIs of Cocoa. The algorithm would be as following:

1. Call `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()` to get info about all windows in system.
2. Extract the windows that you are interested into, the best approach would be to do it via owner pid, as this info is returned by the above function
3. Create an `ImageRef` by calling `CGWindowListCreateImage()`
4. Either obtain the data of the above ImageRef, or save it into a file, via `CGImageDestinationRef` functions.

As Java cannot directly call Cocoa functions, a bridge between Java and Cocoa is needed, a bridge which makes use of JNI to allow Java code to reach the ObjectiveC implemented functions.

Your question posed quite a challenge, so I started a little project of github (https://github.com/cristik/cocoa4java) that provides the functionality needed for taking snapshots of application windows. I think you'll find everything you need there, in terms of finding the windows associated to a process, and retrieving a snapshot of those windows. There's also a small example class that makes use of those functionalities in order to help you get started with the library.

Comment: `JNI, CoreGraphics, ImageIO,  Cocoa` - really? Like I don't know any of those, a lot to read I suppose :-) Thank you for repo; but I generally don't like JNI. It's not that it's wrong - it get's job done but still

Comment: Well, not sure if it can be done without JNI, unless Java will provide access to the Cocoa (the ObjectiveC Mac API) functions. Regarding the frameworks I enumerated, you don't need to read about them unless you want to switch to ObjectiveC, as those frameworks are native :)

Comment: Any chance of a JNA example?